# dominant-baseline doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, alignment

Consider the following example:

```css
g {
  transform: translate(50px, 50px);
  dominant-baseline: central;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="15" stroke="#000" fill="#ffffff" />
    <text x="0" y="0">A</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Chrome respects `dominant-baseline: central` by aligning the text vertically in the middle:

[image]

But, Firefox doesn't seem to respect `dominant-baseline: central`:

[image]

How would you fix this cross browser issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [SVG 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineAlignmentProperties) dominant-baseline is not an inherited property. SVG 2 changes things such that [dominant-baseline is inherited](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#DominantBaselineProperty). Firefox only implemented that SVG 2 feature in version 70. I.e. after this question was originally written.

In the meantime simply set dominant-baseline on the text element.

```css
g {
  transform: translate(50px, 50px);
  text-anchor: middle;
}
text {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="15" stroke="#000" fill="#ffffff" />
    <text x="0" y="0">A</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What a coincidence, I was just fiddling around with the same at https://codepen.io/nachtigall/pen/bRoevR. Is there a bug at BMO to follow?

Comment: Wow, patches already submitted. Robert, I'm really impressed :)