# dominant-baseline behaves differently in Firefox. Why?

Tags: css, svg, vertical-alignment

I noticed that the SVG attribute `dominant-baseline` behaves different in Chrome and Firefox.

The vertical alignment is not exactly the same for `dominant-baseline="hanging"`. In Firefox, the gap between the `path` and the `text` is slightly bigger than in Chrome.

[In Chrome 76.0.3809.132](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uagCh.png)

[In Firefox 69.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ7Cx.png)

I already read [dominant-baseline doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742383/dominant-baseline-doesnt-work-in-firefox) but it doesn't seem to apply here since the attribute is directly on the `<text>` element.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20,20 L180,20" stroke="grey" />
    <text dominant-baseline="hanging" x="30" y="20">Hanging</text>
</svg>
```

Example taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline.

I would expect the vertical alignment to be the same across browsers but it's not. Any idea why ?

Comment: Please take a look at [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: You mean the slightly bigger gap for Hanging?

Comment: All compatibilities are unknown :(

Comment: @RobertLongson yes exactly

Comment: @RobertLongson accepting that `dominant-baseline="hanging"` will behave slightly differently in different browsers, do you know if there is a predictable way to anticipate the pixel gap ? like adding a specific `dx` for Firefox to replicate the behaviour in Chrome for instance.

Comment: I meant `dy` sorry. To correct the gap.

Comment: IMHO text element properties are the least QA'd part of browser SVG

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well.

It seems it was a [known bug in FireFox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1603629) but has been fixed (in v82 Aug-2020 as much as I can see).

So it looks fine  in latest FireFox (87.0):
[image: FireFox 87.0]

[Html code in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/svg-dominant-baseline?file=index.html)

I ran into it because some test automation tools (eg. Percy) still using old firefox version.